# Multiplying TRS Affine Transformations

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, matrix-decomposition

To represent 2D affine transformations I'm using translation, rotation and scale. When I transform a vector I compose the TRS matrix, that is I scale then rotate and finally translate the vector.

That is, given $T, R, S$

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix} t_1 \\ t_2 \end{bmatrix} \\
R = \alpha \\
S = \begin{bmatrix} s_1 \\ s_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $s_1 \neq 0$ and $s_2 \neq 0$, I compose the matrix
$$
M(T,R,S) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
s_1 \cos \alpha & -s_2 \sin \alpha & t_1 \\
s_1 \sin \alpha & s_2 \cos \alpha & t_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and finally use matrix multiplication to transform the vector.

The problem I'm having is when decomposing several $T, R, S$ transformations. With the case the scale is uniform ($s_1 = s_2$) I can decompose two transformations as

$$
M(T,R,S) = M(T',R',S') \cdot M(T'',R'',S'') \\
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
s'(t''_1\cos \alpha'- t''_2\sin \alpha') + t'_1 \\
s'(t''_1\sin \alpha'+ t''_2\cos \alpha') + t'_2 
\end{bmatrix} \\
R = \alpha' + \alpha'' \\
S = \begin{bmatrix} s's'' \\ s's'' \end{bmatrix}
$$
however this only works when scale is uniform.

Is it possible to decompose the above $M(T,R,S)$ matrix to $T,R,S$ form when scale is non-uniform?

When I try it I only end up trying to simplify $a \cos \alpha \cos \beta - b \sin \alpha \sin \beta, b \neq a$ to the form $a' \cos \alpha'$ with no success.

Comment: The two-dimensional affine group is 6-dimensional.  What makes you believe that your  matrices $M(T,R,S)$ form a subgroup?  Probably what you are showing is that unless the scale is uniform, they do not.

Comment: Hmm, that might be the case. However, I have seen decompositions of 3D matrices to translation, scale and unit quaternion, 2D might be different though.

Comment: The decomposition of 3d affine transforms to translation, rotation, and scaling is possible (and closed) when the scaling is uniform. Sometimes 3d math packages will try to pretend that TRS is closed when S is diagonal, but this is incorrect. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html -- it's lossy because it can't represent skew. One general decomposition in 3D is T Ra D Rb where D is a diagonal, and Ra Rb are proper rotations.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's possible that scaling, rotating and repeating can add shear so José was right, with non-uniform scale it's not possible.